Can I tell in python if my class is used in context?
I am working on a small hobby project using Python. I wish to "do it right", and follow common guidelines.
Following an example package using SQLite, I can make things work fine by using context.
Example:
import mypackage as mp

with mp.democlass() as dc:
    dc.dosomething('some_parameter')

This obviously calls the __enter__ and __exit__ functions.
If I wish to package my work so that it can also be used without the with  function, example:
dc = mp.democlass()
dc.dosomething('some_parameter')

.. what would be the "correct" approach. Can I determine in the class if it is used in with context, or do I need to code an identical initialization function to __enter__, example to open a database connection.
I hope the question makes sense. Maybe I need a boilerplate module which has both ways.

If __enter__ is called you know that you are (probably) in a with context (unless it someone calls it explicitly). Then you could e.g. set a flag. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to know.

include doesn't exist in Python; that should be import instead.

does with create its own scope?

@cards If you mean variable scope, I don't think so. dc can be referenced after existing with, but the object it refers to will have been closed by whatever its __exit__() method does.

you could use the contextlib.contextmanager to make clear (readable in terms of writing code) when you use a with. Keep in mind that you will probably need to redesign a bit the task

There are quite a few classes, even in Python standard library, which can use a context just as an option. (For example, concurrent.futures executors, or even the object returned by a built-in file open call)
The general pattern is that one creates all needed resources directly in the __init__ method, and the __enter__ method becomes essentially a "no-op" with its body being, usually, a single return self line.
In these cases, whatever resource-clean up has to be performed (for example, commiting a transaction) can be done in a public method (which could be named close or commit) - and the __exit__ method will call that method from its body. The __del__ method in the class will be called, in a deterministic way, if the object is simply de-referenced in a "happy path" - but it could actually never run in edge cases, like, when an exception takes place and the interpreter exits. All documentation (and my own live experience) is unanimous in disrecomending adding important clean-up actions solely as part of a __del__ method (btw, exceptions raised inside a __del__ method are swallowed, and swallowed and just printed-out to stderr, with no other effect in the running program)
This way, people are free to use the resource outside of a with  context manager block, but in doing so, take the responsibility of ensuring the clean-up method will be called.
